# Magento2 - How to remove "or" from header.links

Tags: magento2, theme

How can I remove the `or` from the `sign in` link?
It currently says `sign in or` (default), and I would like to remove the `or` because I don't need it.
Here a screenshot of it (in german):

[image]

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Copy `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml` from Customer module to your theme:

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml`.

And then, try to remove or hidden `data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('or')); ?>"`.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find "account/link/authorization.phtml", whats the full path?

Comment: Updated my answer!